# align environment not entirely functional in beamer

Tags: beamer, align

I am currently working on a [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) project where I use the `align` enviroment. My code is as follows:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The Hovorka model}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
The Hovorka model as an IVP:
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{\dot{x}}(t) = f(\boldsymbol{x}(t),d_k,u_k,\boldsymbol{\theta}_k)\\
\boldsymbol{x}(t_0) = \boldsymbol{x_0} \\
f : \left( \mathbb{R}^{n_x}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^{n_\theta} \right) \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n_x}
\end{align*}
CGM model:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dG_I}{dt}(t) = -\frac{(G_I(t)-G(t))}{\tau_I} \\
G_{CGM}(t) = G_I(t) + \varepsilon_n \\
\varepsilon_n = \left( \xi +\lambda \cdot  \sinh \left(\frac{e_n - \gamma}{\delta} \right) \right)
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Hovorka}\\
16 variable parameters
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
```

If I may lead your attention to the first `align*` environment I try to align the following using `&`:

```
\begin{align*}
    \boldsymbol{\dot{x}}(t) &= f(\boldsymbol{x}(t),d_k,u_k,\boldsymbol{\theta}_k)\\
    \boldsymbol{x}(t_0) &= \boldsymbol{x_0} \\
    f &: \left( \mathbb{R}^{n_x}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^{n_\theta} \right) \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n_x}
    \end{align*}
```

By doing this I get approximately 20-30 error codes, where the first three is:

```
! Argument of \align has an extra }.<inserted text>\par \end{frame}
! Paragraph ended before \align was complete.<to be read again>\par \end{frame}
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \end{frame}
```

Now, I am confused why this is happening beacuse the only thing I am adding is the three `&` as usually works outside the frame environment. Somehow, it does not work inside the frame environment. Do you have any idea why I cannot align inside my frame environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frame environment is not the problem, but the `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The Hovorka model}
    \begin{columns}

        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

            The Hovorka model as an IVP:
            \begin{align*}
                \boldsymbol{\dot{x}}(t) &= f(\boldsymbol{x}(t),d_k,u_k,\boldsymbol{\theta}_k)\\
                \boldsymbol{x}(t_0) &= \boldsymbol{x_0} \\
                f &: \left( \mathbb{R}^{n_x}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^{n_\theta} \right) \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n_x}
            \end{align*}
            CGM model:
            \begin{align*}
                \frac{dG_I}{dt}(t) = -\frac{(G_I(t)-G(t))}{\tau_I} \\
                G_{CGM}(t) = G_I(t) + \varepsilon_n \\
                \varepsilon_n = \left( \xi +\lambda \cdot  \sinh \left(\frac{e_n - \gamma}{\delta} \right) \right)
            \end{align*}

        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Hovorka}
        \end{column}    

        \end{columns}   
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Samcarter - this solved my problem! I appreciate your help!